# How to stop the looking for css classes in the workspace - VSCODE

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

I am using VsCode for web development purposes, i clicked the format document with once, like 2 weeks ago and since then whenever i have VsCode open it keeps showing the following message [Loooking for Css classes in the workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dh0T.png) it is making my laptop terribly slow, making vscode extensions stop working and my website takes lots of time to load on live server (i did not add/change/remove any content since the problem occured, so i do not think that the problem is caused by loading a certain resource) any help of how i can stop this formatting is really appreciated.

Comment: first try with disabling ALL extensions

Comment: @rioV8 i found it, the problem was caused by IntelliSense for CSS class names in HTML
zignd.html-css-class-completion
Zignd

Comment: then file an issue at the extension to only process MODIFIED files

Answer (score 6):

I found it, the problem was caused by IntelliSense for CSS class names in HTML **zignd.html-css-class-completion Zignd.**

Disabling it solved my problem, vscode runs much smoother now.

Comment: You saved me a lot of headache! Vscode was constantly running out of memory and crashing. Disabling this extension solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have installed Css Intellisense extension. In the extension setting you can define in which folder or which file type to scan for the workspace. This make the scan less demanding.